# converting .c file to .o using processes

Tags: c++, c, gcc, .a

I have to make a project which asks me to create a program that will compile a C project by recursively descending into directories and launching processes which compile a file of code by calling GCC and look through directories and launch a new process for every ".c" file in the current directory that process will call gcc on the .c file making a .o file.

I have written this code so far to list the directories first
I am having trouble checking what files are .c and how to convert them to .o

```
can someone help me with some relevant information/links that I can refer to? 




void listdir(const char *name, int indent)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;

    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
        return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry->d_name, "..") == 0)
                continue;
            snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
            printf("%*s[%s]\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
            listdir(path, indent + 2);
        } else {
            printf("%*s- %s\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
        }
    }
    closedir(dir);
}

int main(void) {
    listdir(".", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to write a `make file`?

Comment: If you know about `strcmp()`, you should be able to find a standard function to check for filenames ending in ".c", shouldn't you?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment or something? Because if it isn't, then there's really no reason to reinvent the wheel, as `make` can already do pretty much exactly what you want (and more)

Comment: It is a Homework assignment, although I can't find any relevant information on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `fork()` and `exec()` in order to get a `.o` file it should look something like this

```
  if ((forkmefool[i] = fork()) < 0)
  {
      printf("no Procceses");
      exit(0);
  }
  else if (forkmefool[i] == 0)
  {

      char *args[] = {"cc", entry->d_name, "-c", NULL};
      execv("/usr/bin/cc", args);
  }
```

take a note of `exec()`

Comment: btw entry->d_name is just a variable you can put any file there